# Change product image issue in Minicart Magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin, mini-cart

I am trying to change product image in minicart,

Used below code to achieve it.

here is the code of my di.xml file.

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
 <plugin name="Change_Product_Image_In_Minicart" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Minicart\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

This code i used in my plugin file Image.php

```
 class Image
 {
    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item){
     $result = $proceed($item);
     $productImage = "some image link"; 
     $result['product_image']['src'] = $productImage;   
     return $result;
   }
 }
```

I am getting below erro once used above code,

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION),
>   Anyone suggest what is mistake here please,
>       }

I have fixed the issue myself, can anybody update me code for, how to change image for each item in the minicart, suppose if i have 5 items in cart, i need to change image for each of them, How can i apply for each here?

Comment: which type of image you want , is that custom image attribute or one of product gallery image ?

Comment: Some image url is stored in custom table, where i am wrong here?

Comment: did you directly copy paste the code from the browser, a PDF, or an advanced text editor, I think that error because the encoding problem ?

Comment: did you forget class closing { ?

Comment: no, i am closing it

Comment: how to fix the encoding issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to type the code manually

Answer (score 0):

In this topic we will do How to Change Product Image in Minicart

Step 1: Create di.xml file

Step 2: Create Image.php file

Product image in minicart will getten to  show by function doGetItemData() in Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem class but this function is protected, so we cannot use plugin on it. Instead, it extends from Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem and use function getItemData()

First We need to create registration and module file as per structure of magento 2 then follow below steps.

Step 1: Create di.xml file

Create di.xml file in app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/etc/frontend

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
     <plugin name="Change_Product_Image_In_Minicart" type="[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create Image.php file

Create Image.php file in app/code/[Name_Space][Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart

```
<?php

namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart;

class Image
{

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item)
    {

        $result = $proceed($item);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($result['product_id']);

        /* thum url */ 
        $storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        if($product->getThumbnail()){
            $result['product_image']['src'] = $mediaUrl.$product->getThumbnail();
        }
        else{
            $result['product_image']['src'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```